# How to create a diagram for the content of a text?

Tags: table-of-contents, diagrams

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Draw Image (Data flow)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8879/draw-image-data-flow)

I would insert in a document TeX a diagram representing the relations of dependence between its contents. I mean something like the diagram on page 5 of [Modern Computer Algebra of von zur Gathen and Gerhard](http://books.google.com/books?id=NuEHj0wPwgIC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q&f=false).

(Warning about the example referred: I am looking at the function of that example and not at its specific realization.)

I am starting to use LaTeX, so I would know what are the more efficient, minimal ways to realize it. Any suggestion is wellcome, thank you.

P.S. Any help to make this question more intellegible is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a way of somehow *generating* such a diagram from your document's section titles, or do you just want to draw one "by hand"?

Comment: I thought that it should be introduced by hand, because eventually there is not a linear order between its items, and I should specify the linking by hand.

Comment: I would suggest using TikZ to draw the diagram. You should be able to build on the answer given in [Draw Image (Data flow)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8879/draw-image-data-flow)

Comment: Dear Jake, thank you for the attention and the suggestion.  The answers to that question adapt to my case too. I have to look them closer.

Comment: Glad it helps. Feel free to ask a new question if you run into trouble creating your graph. I would suggest we close this one as a duplicate of the one I linked to.