# Drawing a data flow diagram in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Would it be possible to draw a data flow diagram in LaTeX as follow? if so, how? (actually I am only puzzled with the bounding box).

Thanks a lot

[image: A dataflow diagram]

Edit: the following code will get me everything except the bounding box can anyone pls help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  font=\rmfamily\footnotesize,
  every matrix/.style={ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=2cm,row sep=.6cm},
  source/.style={draw,thick,rounded corners,fill=yellow!20,inner sep=.3cm},
  process/.style={draw,thick,circle,fill=blue!20},
  sink/.style={source,fill=green!20},
  datastore/.style={draw,very thick,shape=datastore,inner sep=.3cm},
  dots/.style={gray,scale=2},
  to/.style={->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,semithick,font=\rmfamily\scriptsize},
  every node/.style={align=center}]

  % Position the nodes using a matrix layout
  \matrix{
    \node[source] (a) {A}; \& \& \\
     \& \& \node[source] (b) {B};\\
     \node[source] (c) {C}; \& \node[source] (d) {D};\\
     \& \& \node[source] (e) {E};\\
     \node[source] (f) {F}; \& \& \\      
  };

  % Draw the arrows between the nodes and label them.
  \draw[to] (a) -- node[midway,above] {raw events}
      node[midway,below] {level 0} (c);
  \draw[to] (c) -- node[midway,right] {raw event data\\level 1} (f);
  \draw[to] (f) to[bend right=20] node[midway,above] {events}
      node[midway,below] {level 1} (d);
  \draw[to] (d)-- node[midway,above] {events}
      node[midway,below] {level 1} (b);
  \draw[to] (d) -- node[midway,above] {events}
      node[midway,below] {level 1} (e);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: if you could post what you have so far, someone could probably finish it. the `fit` library would probably be useful

Comment: Check some examples at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/porter-model/ and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8879/draw-image-data-flow  and Linked Q's for a good starting point.

Comment: You could search something like [`[tikz-pgf] fit flow`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btikz-pgf%5D+fit+flow). The [third find](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116621/16595) on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Atex.stackexchange.com+flow+tikz+chart+diagram+usetikzlibrary+fit) should also be helpful.

Comment: @BaoRu Thanks for posting your example code.

Comment: You can find similar boxes in [how-to-create-the-following-figures-in-tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145883/how-to-create-the-following-figures-in-tikz/145986#145986)

Comment: For a different solution than the fit library, you might want to have a look to [High level digital design in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110209/13304).

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the comments, the `fit` library is designed exactly for this purpose. One thing to know about the `fit` node is that it's hard to put text inside it any place other than its centre, so to label the dotted parts, you need to place separate nodes by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,fit,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  font=\rmfamily\footnotesize,
  every matrix/.style={ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=2cm,row sep=.6cm},
  source/.style={draw,thick,rounded corners,fill=yellow!20,inner sep=.3cm},
  process/.style={draw,thick,circle,fill=blue!20},
  sink/.style={source,fill=green!20},
  datastore/.style={draw,very thick,shape=datastore,inner sep=.3cm},
  dots/.style={gray,scale=2},
  to/.style={->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,semithick,font=\rmfamily\scriptsize},
  every node/.style={align=center}]

  % Position the nodes using a matrix layout
  \matrix{
    \node[source] (a) {A}; \& \& \\
     \& \& \node[source] (b) {B};\\
     \node[source] (c) {C}; \& \node[source] (d) {D};\\
     \& \& \node[source] (e) {E};\\
     \node[source] (f) {F}; \& \& \\      
  };

  % Draw the arrows between the nodes and label them.
  \draw[to] (a) -- node[midway,above] {raw events}
      node[midway,below] {level 0} (c);
  \draw[to] (c) -- node[midway,right] {raw event data\\level 1} (f);
  \draw[to] (f) to[bend right=20] node[midway,above] {events}
      node[midway,below] {level 1} (d);
  \draw[to] (d)-- node[midway,above] {events}
      node[midway,below] {level 1} (b);
  \draw[to] (d) -- node[midway,above] {events}
      node[midway,below] {level 1} (e);
  % Draw the dotted surrounding lines and add the labels as separate nodes
  % This is necessary because the anchor of the fitted node is always center

  \node[draw,dotted,fit=(a) (c) (f),inner sep=4ex,] (ACF) {};
  \node[above=-3ex of ACF] (ACFt) {Title 1};
  \node[draw,dotted,fit=(b) (e), inner sep=4ex] (BE) {};
  \node[above=-3ex of BE] (Bet) {Title 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]